# feeding raw data as image to deep learning machine and expecting to create an image for given class

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning, prediction

I know that deep learning is capable of many cool stuff to do with images.
the question that i am facing is:
is it possible to create a bitmap image of a large data for multiple class and feed it to a deep learning image processing machine, and when trained expect the machine to generate an image for the given class?

for example predicting a sport match; giving an image of the statics of each game as input, and the class would be the name of two teams.
so when I enter "New England Patriots - Seattle Seahawks" the AI generate an image that is the prediction of statics of the game.

will doing so help prediction in anyway?

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you are asking. So you want to train the machine to output a picture containing statistics of a game given input: "team 1" and "team 2"?

Comment: yes, what i am asking, is it a good idea?

Comment: I'm not sure that the image portion of this is going to be helpful. The network would spend a majority of its time learning to generate images, and not learning to predict game statistics. Perhaps a network where the output nodes correspond with one particular statistic: number of points, number of sacks, etc.

Comment: well, thats right, but my thought was that i can show more important statics bigger in image (like goals) so it would help learning data better.

Comment: I think, in general, that the more work the algorithm has to do to get to the useful data, the harder it will be to learn the data. Remember machines can't "see" images like we can. Imagine if I were to bit-encode a bunch of data and ask you to learn it. You would have to spend most of your time decoding, and not much time learning the task. The same is true for these algorithms here. If you want to give important statistics more weight, you can simply include a weight term to your algorithm.

Comment: So at the end it just makes things more complicated than simple! Well thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2):

This is an open reasearch topic called Generative Adversarial Networks. An explanation of this can be found here: https://www.quora.com/What-are-Generative-Adversarial-Networks.

Example paper usage: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.07828v1.pdf?utm_campaign=Machine%2BLearning%2BWeekly&utm_medium=web&utm_source=Machine_Learning_Weekly_9.

Example youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=deyOX6Mt_As.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that was really great lead to where i wanted to go, but  my question had another part, is this technique a good idea for prediction of sport matches or similar type of data?

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine. I do not think anyone ever tried this. However here is a model that generates images from text: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.05396v2.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to create a bitmap image [...] for multiple class and feed it to a deep learning image processing machine, and when trained expect the machine to generate an image for the given class?

As Thomas already wrote, what you might want to have a look at is called "Generative Adversarial Networks" (GAN).

However, it is not as simple to train those as to train feed-forward multilayer perceptrons. You can't simply have the class + noise as input and expect it to generate realistic output images. The problem is:

1. there are many realistic images (32px x 32px, RGB -> 255^(32*32*3) possible images)
2. you only know for several million images that they are realistic

The solution is to train two networks which play a game: The generator network G, which generates images. And the discriminator network D, which has to decide if the input comes from the generator or from the natural image source.

> for example predicting a sport match; giving an image of the statics of each game as input, and the class would be the name of two teams. so when I enter "New England Patriots - Seattle Seahawks" the AI generate an image that is the prediction of statics of the game.

I'm not sure if I understand what you want. However, if you simply what to display something like

"1:0"

as an image ... why should you use machine learning at all for the displaying-part? Why not simply predict the outcome (machine learning) and  generate an image the usual way with probably 3 simple lines of code?

> by so many good image processing application in deep learning, will it help me to achieve result more quickly than just input data directly

No. This just adds complexity which has to be solved by the image processing algorithms. After "solving" those problems you artificially added to the dataset, it can tackle the problem you could have given it directly.

> i was thinking that i can show more important data like goal scores bigger in the image, so it has more impact in future results

If you know what is important and in which relationship, then don't use machine learning.

Comment: Well, first of all thanks for your reply, secondly the image that i am feeding to machine is like a QR code (no noise) and it has all the statics of the game, and the image that i am expecting has all the statics as the original images.

Comment: Then you should probably update the question and answer clearly what your input and what your expected output is. If your input is image statistics, then why don't you input it directly? Why do you take the indirection of an image?

Comment: Well, that was actually my question, by so many good image processing application in deep learning, will it help me to achieve result more quickly than just input data directly.

Comment: And also, i was thinking that i can show more important data like goal scores bigger in the image, so it has more impact in future results.

Comment: @AshkanGhodrat I've expanded my answer.